# Trouble invoking AJAX to link to internal page in PHP single page app

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've looked at a lot of StackOverflow answers but can't find an answer that is working. This seems like it should be so simple.

I have a PHP single page web app. It has a nav bar that loads pages as includes. Clicking the nav bar invokes a jQuery function to load a different include and inject a class into a div. This works in the nav.

In one of the includes, I have an HTML link:

```
<div class="page-content">
    <a class='btn-primary'>See Examples</a>
</div>
```

This is the jQuery I want it to execute:

```
$(".btn-primary").click(function() {
    alert('you clicked me');
    $('.page').attr('class', 'page examples');
    // REPLACE THE CURRENT INCLUDE
    $('.page-content').load('includes/page-examples.php');
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});
```

But the link does not execute the function. Changing it to a div does not work. Clicking will not even execute the alert.

**I've tried to put the link in php echo or php print**, but it makes no difference. I've checked all my naming and there isn't a typo.

What is the best way to make it work?

----- EDIT -----

The jQuery is being called from a js file called from the index.php head tag, and is in the DOM ready statement. It looks like the DOM is ready before the include with the link loads. If I remove the link's js from the js file and put it in the include with the link, then the link works, but this will create a problem as other internal links are added to the site in other includes.

What is the best way to fix ?

Comment: I tried that here: https://gist.github.com/lukaskuzmiak/19c4c738799fe6c8ee181449ff9bc5da and it works fine, seems like the problem is elsewhere in your code - maybe the javascript is executed before the DOM is loaded?

Comment: It's in the DOM ready. I will look at your gist, thank you!

Comment: If I take the script out of the js file and put it in the include that contains the link, then it works. But I don't want to have global js in my includes - if I put the link in another include, I would have to include the js there also (this problem would grow with every link). What is the right way to solve this?

Comment: sounds like the javascript is maybe executed on page load (document ready) before the include is included if that's over AJAX? If so, add a callback to the loading of the include and do the click binding there.

Comment: I don't fully understand your recommendation though you are right that the DOM is ready before the include arrives. Can you provide example showing exactly what to do? If it works, I will select the answer as the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your javascript click binding `$(".btn-primary").click(...);` is executed on DOM-ready.

But at that time the `.btn-primary` is not yet in the DOM as it only gets inserted into the DOM after you include it (if I understood it right).

Therefore the binding never happens and after your first include gets loaded the click binding code is never executed again and therefore the `.btn-primary` element has no onClick event.

You need to run your javascript snippet after that `.btn-primary` element gets inserted in the DOM, eg. like this:

```
$('.page-content').load('includes/first-include.php', function(){
    $(".btn-primary").click(function() {
        whatever...
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**First step**

> Check if you are importing jQuery library (it seems obvious, but we
>   can forget to import the library sometimes or the library URL is wrong
>   and the browser cannot recognize it as well). And remember you need import jQuery before the function you wrote.

**Second step**

If you need to inject a class into some element using jQuery, the easiest way to do this is:

Instead...

```
$('.page').attr('class', 'page examples');
```

Change to...

```
$('.page').addClass('examples');
```

In this example above, you can omit the 'page' and let only 'examples', because the class ".page" is already there.

Another thing, this will only work if the element with ".page" class already exists in your HTML.

**Third step:**

Add a callback to .load function and see if it worked properly:

```
$('.page-content').load('includes/page-examples.php', function(){
  alert("Nice, my content was loaded!");

  // You can put this action here, so it will execute after the content is loaded
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for looking at this. Yes, jQuery is loaded and is working in all of the nav. I'm using attr instead of "addClass" because I want to replace other classes that may be attached, not remove them individually. I am not sure I understand your load function. The load is already a part of link's click function, and it does not work.

Comment: Hi, you're welcome! Yes, you are doing well with the classes replacement using attr. The code I sent above is actually inside the click button event, as in your code. I only added up there the event click button content.

Comment: Ohhhh, yes, I see. I didn't understand that clearly.